# Could not pass data from one file to another on first run - android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have 2 files -> **Mainactivity** and **GcmIntentService**

My gcmregister.php returns a token. I use the variable responce to store the returned token. I am trying to return this token to MainActivity.java using putString. Then i am trying to send the token to the other file and save it in usrfromdb. The problem is that when i install the app and run it for the first time the token is not saved in usrfromdb. But if I close the app and reopen everything looks fine. Please help.

**Mainactivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

WebView view;
String usrfromdb;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    usrfromdb = sharedPreferences.getString("userfromdb","");

    if(usrfromdb=="") {
        if (checkPlayServices()) {
            registerGCM();

            usrfromdb = sharedPreferences.getString("userfromdb","Not Available");
         }
    }
}

private void registerGCM() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, GcmIntentService.class);
    intent.putExtra("key", "register");
    startService(intent);
}
.....
}
```

**GcmIntentService.java**

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {

private static final String TAG = GcmIntentService.class.getSimpleName();

public GcmIntentService() {
    super(TAG);
}


@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
      registerGCM();
}

private void registerGCM() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    try {
        InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
        String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
                GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);

        Log.e(TAG, "GCM Registration Token: " + token);

        URL url = new URL("http://www.fut.bg/gcmregister.php");
        Map<String,Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        params.put("app", "mfutbg");
        params.put("regId", token);

        StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
        for (Map.Entry<String,Object> param : params.entrySet()) {
            if (postData.length() != 0) postData.append('&');
            postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            postData.append('=');
            postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
        }
        byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);

        Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int c; (c = in.read()) >= 0;)
            sb.append((char)c);
        String response = sb.toString();


        Log.e(TAG, "userfromdb: " + response);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("userfromdb", response);
        editor.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to complete token refresh", e);
      }
}
```

}

Comment: GcmIntentService its run separate thread (http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/reference/android/app/IntentService.html). you will get the token and send to server and store the data in usrfromdb on time x on separate task thread. but you request the usrfromdb at time y on your main thread. you never get.

Answer (score 0):

one class

```
intent.putExtra("spcl", spcl);
intent.putExtra("img", img);
```

get data from another class like this

```
sprice = getIntent().getStringExtra("spcl");
image = getIntent().getStringExtra("img");
```